# Accelerometer Problems in React-Native/Expo

Tags: react-native, accelerometer, expo

I'm building an app on codeHS that utilizes an accelerometer.

I tried dragging and dropping the accelerometer component the website provides into the code I was writing just to see how the component would work.

When I tried to run the code the debugger gave me an error, stating that it couldn't read the `addListener` event, stating that it was undefined. What is causing the error? I appreciate any insight or tips.

Here is a copy of the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, View, Listener, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Constants, Accelerometer } from 'expo';

export default class App extends Component {
componentWillUnmount() {
    this._unsubscribeFromAccelerometer();
}

componentDidMount() {
    this._subscribeToAccelerometer();
}

state = {
    accelerometerData: { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }
};

_subscribeToAccelerometer = () => {
    this._acceleroMeterSubscription = Accelerometer.addListener(accelerometerData =>
        this.setState({ accelerometerData })
    );
};

_unsubscribeFromAccelerometer = () => {
    this._acceleroMeterSubscription && this._acceleroMeterSubscription.remove();
    this._acceleroMeterSubscription = null;
};

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.paragraph}>

                <Text>
                    Accelerometer:
                    x = {this.state.accelerometerData.x.toFixed(2)}{', '}
                    y = {this.state.accelerometerData.y.toFixed(2)}{', '}
                    z = {this.state.accelerometerData.z.toFixed(2)}
                </Text>
            </Text>
        </View>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: I don't know Expo well, but is it possible that Expo needs to initialise first, so that the Accelerometer isn't instantiated yet by the time you want to call .addListener on it?